# Sorting after search is performed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC where I am able to search the database for different values. I am also able to sort the list in both ascending and descending order of for example prise and alphabet.
But lets say that I have a total of 10 rows in the database. I then make a search which gives two results. If I then try to sort those two it reloads all the 10 rows again.

How am I able to make a sorting after a search without it reloading the entire list?

**My controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, string sortOrder)
{

    ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.TextSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "text_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.PriceSortParm = sortOrder == "Price" ? "price_desc" : "Price";
    ViewBag.CubicMeterSortParm = sortOrder == "CubicMeter" ? "cubicMeter_desc" : "CubicMeter";
    ViewBag.PricePerCubicSortParm = sortOrder == "PricePerCubic" ? "pricePerCubic_desc" : "PricePerCubic";

    var text = from s in db.LearningNumbers select s;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            text = text.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
            break;
        case "text_desc":
            text = text.OrderByDescending(s => s.Note);
            break;
        case "Price":
            text = text.OrderBy(s => s.Price);
            break;
        case "price_desc":
            text = text.OrderByDescending(s => s.Price);
            break;
        case "CubicMeter":
            text = text.OrderBy(s => s.CubicMeter);
            break;
        case "cubicMeter_desc":
            text = text.OrderByDescending(s => s.CubicMeter);
            break;
        case "PricePerCubic":
            text = text.OrderBy(s => s.PricePerCubic);
            break;
        case "pricePerCubic_desc":
            text = text.OrderByDescending(s => s.PricePerCubic);
            break;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        if (searchBy == "Tekst")
        {
            text = text.Where(x => x.Note.Contains(search) || search == null);
        }
        else
        {
            text = text.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search) || search == null); 
        }
    }

    return View(text.ToList());
}
```

**My view:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Navn", true) <text>Navn</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Tekst") <text>Tekst</text><br />
    @Html.TextBox("search")<input class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:0 10px;" type="submit" value="Søg" />
}

<div class="col-md-12 table" style="display:table; margin:45px 0 25px 0;">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @*<b>Tekst</b><br />*@
        <h4>@Html.ActionLink("Navn", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm })</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @*<b>Tekst</b><br />*@
        <h4>
            @Html.ActionLink("Tekst", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TextSortParm })
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @*<b>Kostpris med tillæg</b><br />*@
        <h4>
            @Html.ActionLink("Kostpris med tillæg", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PriceSortParm })
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @*<b>Brutto m2</b><br />*@
        <h4>
            @Html.ActionLink("Brutto m2", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.CubicMeterSortParm })
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @*<b>Kostpris pr m2 bygning</b><br />*@
        <h4>
            @Html.ActionLink("Kostpris pr m2 bygning", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PricePerCubicSortParm })
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>

@if (Model.Count() == 0)
{
    <h3>Beklager! Vi fandt desværre ingen resultater med dine søgekriterier.</h3>
    <p>Prøv venligst igen.</p>
}
else
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {

        <div class="col-md-12 table" style="display: table; margin: 0 0 0 0; ">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CubicMeter)</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PricePerCubic)</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr />

    }
}
```

Comment: You are returning the view before you sort.

Comment: I did try to sort before I return the view but without any result. When I look closer at the debugging it looks like I am missing my search string when I try to sort. I tried with `text = text.OrderBy(s => s.Price).Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search);` but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Comment above has it.

Don't return the view until the very end of your function. Create the collection and save it to a local variable.

Then on that local variable call your order by clause.

Pseudo-code:

```
var results = search();


If (orderBy)
{
    Results = results.orderBy(X);
}

return view(Results);
```

Comment: I have now edited the code so I should only return the view at the end. But it still doesnt solve my problem. It still shows all nodes after a search.

Comment: Maybe I am being dumb, but I don't see you passing back the sort param to the controller for any of your controller calls. Do you have anything in the search string in the controller when searching?

Comment: I am pretty new at MVC and C# so I might be asking the wrong questions here. After searching my searchstring in the URL looks like this: `?searchBy=Tekst&search=car`. If I search "car" and if I debug at shows "car" in the search string.

Comment: OK, if it is making it to your controller then you are fine. I must have been being blind. So after the search your text list is still 10 elements?

Comment: The search works fine. I have 3 nodes with "car" in the name. If I search "car" I get 3 results. If I then afterwards (while having the 3 results showing) presses one of the link to for example sort by price - it sorts - but it shows all the 10 notes again and not only the 3 I just narroved it down to with my search.

Comment: Ah. Now it all makes sense. The issue is that on the sort you are having to re-hit the data so you are no longer filtering to the search. Make your action links pass in the search and search by params like you are doing for the sort

Comment: Hmm. Alright. I can see where you are going at but I am not sure how to do it. I have tried to include the entire switch within the `if (searchBy == "Tekst")` and `else` but with no luck. I am sorry if I am being a bit slow here. If it is not too much trouble could I you please show a short example?

Comment: In your various sorting action links you pass in the sortOrder, but not the current search. Try passing in the search there so that you have it the second time. @Html.ActionLink("Kostpris pr m2 bygning", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.PricePerCubicSortParm })

Comment: Thank you Jim. Now I know what you mean. I just needs to figure out how to pass the searchstring in the actionlink. I will take a look at it. Thanks!